# Fan control script for Thinkpad X230

Tags: thinkpad, fan

When running Linux Puppy on my previous Thinkpad, an X31, I used a script (found here: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Talk:Problem_with_fan_noise) at startup to control what temperature the CPU fan comes on at. The script begins with:

```
IBM_ACPI=/proc/acpi/ibm
THERMOMETER=$IBM_ACPI/thermal
FAN=$IBM_ACPI/fan
MAXTRIPPOINT=65
MINTRIPPOINT=60
TRIPPOINT=$MINTRIPPOINT
```

On my current Thinkpad, an X230, although the file "/proc/acpi/ibm/fan" exists, "/proc/acpi/ibm/thermal" does not, which seems to be why the script doesn't work on this laptop.

Is there any way I could adjust this script so it would work on my X230?

Thanks for any help.